# How to invoke a method depends on the another method's parameter?

Tags: java

Imagine that I've a method which invoke another method inside. It may look like the following:

```
public void enclosingMethod(String parameter, boolean order){
    MyType t = new MyType();
    t.internalMethod(paramter, order);
}

public void internalMethod(String parameter, boolean order){
    anotherMethod1(str1, order1);
    //etcetera
    anotherMethod31312(str31312, order31312);
}
```

Where `anotherMethodn, 0 < n < 31312` implements as follows:

```
anotherMethodn(String parameter = "default", boolean order = true){
    //Implementation
}
```

The thing is I need to invoke one of anotherMethods depends on the parameter passed to the `internalMethod(String parameter, boolean order)`. For instance, I invoke `enclosingMethod` method as follows:

```
enclosingMethod("PartnerStatistic", false);
```

In this case I need to invoke `anotherMethod23("PartnerStatistic", false)`, but another `anotherMethod`s must be invoked with default argument's value.

How can I do it more flexible rather than to write`if-else` clause many times ? May be there is a suitable well-know design pattern for?

Comment: Does Java have default parameters value?

Comment: @talex Of course, not. This is the thing I ask this question.

Comment: It seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why on earth do you want to have 31312 methods ? What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: If rules that guide you which methods to invoke is random, then you have not so much options. But if they constrained in some way, for example there are fixed amount of string that can be used as `parameter`, simplification is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java if you don't know what method you'll need to invoke, you can use reflection to invoke the method specified by its name.

Example:

```
ClassName.class.getMethod("anotherMethod31312").invoke(instance, arg1, arg2);
```

You still have to "calculate" the name of the method somehow, but you can avoid using extensive `if-else` structures this way. This "calculation" can be by receiving the name of the method to call for example, or depending on your case can be simple `String` concatenation like `"anotherMethod" + i` where `i` is a number.

Also Java has no default parameters. To "simulate" default parameters, you can create an *overload* of the method which calls the other passing default values for the parameters.

Example to simulate default parameters:

```
public void doSomething(String someParam) {
}

public void doSomething() {
    doSomething("This is the default value for 'someParam'.");
}
```

And using it:

```
// Calling doSomething() with explicit parameter:
doSomething("My custom parameter");

// Calling doSomething() with default parameters:
doSomething();
```